# EF6, Linq to entities queries all columns with select new clause

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, linq

Not sure what is going on here, but my query is using every column even though I'm using a projection.

```
var students = (from x in db.vStudentProfiles
   where x.strLegalFirstName == searchDTO.FirstName &&
     x.strLegalMiddleName == searchDTO.MiddleName &&
     x.strLegalLastName == searchDTO.LastName &&
     x.datBirthDate == searchDTO.DateOfBirth &&
     x.intStudentStatusCd != 3 
   orderby x.intStudentStatusCd ascending, x.datCreated descending
    select new
    { 
        x.strLegalFirstName,
        x.strLegalLastName,
        x.strLegalMiddleName,
        x.datBirthDate,
        x.intStudentStatusCd,
        x.datCreated,
        x.strNBEN
    }
   ).ToList();
```

which results in all columns getting queried:

```
    SELECT 
        [Project1].[C1] AS [C1], 
        [Project1].[strLegalFirstName] AS [strLegalFirstName], 
        [Project1].[strLegalLastName] AS [strLegalLastName], 
        [Project1].[strLegalMiddleName] AS [strLegalMiddleName], 
        [Project1].[datBirthDate] AS [datBirthDate], 
        [Project1].[intStudentStatusCd] AS [intStudentStatusCd], 
        [Project1].[datCreated] AS [datCreated], 
        [Project1].[strNBEN] AS [strNBEN]
        FROM ( SELECT 
            [Extent1].[strNBEN] AS [strNBEN], 
            [Extent1].[strLegalFirstName] AS [strLegalFirstName], 
            [Extent1].[strLegalMiddleName] AS [strLegalMiddleName], 
            [Extent1].[strLegalLastName] AS [strLegalLastName], 
            [Extent1].[datBirthDate] AS [datBirthDate], 
            [Extent1].[datCreated] AS [datCreated], 
            [Extent1].[intStudentStatusCd] AS [intStudentStatusCd], 
            1 AS [C1]
            FROM (SELECT 
        [vStudentProfile].[intStudentId] AS [intStudentId], 
        [vStudentProfile].[strStudentStatusDescE] AS [strStudentStatusDescE], 
        [vStudentProfile].[strSPID] AS [strSPID], 
        [vStudentProfile].[strSPIDPart1] AS [strSPIDPart1], 
        [vStudentProfile].[strSPIDPart3] AS [strSPIDPart3], 
        [vStudentProfile].[strSPIDPart4] AS [strSPIDPart4], 
........ bunch of other columns
        [vStudentProfile].[strStreetDirection] AS [strStreetDirection], 
        [vStudentProfile].[strProvince] AS [strProvince], 
        [vStudentProfile].[intStudentStatusCd] AS [intStudentStatusCd], 
        [vStudentProfile].[intSiteId] AS [intSiteId]
    FROM [dbo].[vStudentProfile] AS [vStudentProfile]) AS [Extent1]
        WHERE (([Extent1].[strLegalFirstName] = @p__linq__0) OR (([Extent1].[strLegalFirstName] IS NULL) AND (@p__linq__0 IS NULL))) AND (([Extent1].[strLegalMiddleName] = @p__linq__1) OR (([Extent1].[strLegalMiddleName] IS NULL) AND (@p__linq__1 IS NULL))) AND (([Extent1].[strLegalLastName] = @p__linq__2) OR (([Extent1].[strLegalLastName] IS NULL) AND (@p__linq__2 IS NULL))) AND ([Extent1].[datBirthDate] = @p__linq__3) AND (3 <> [Extent1].[intStudentStatusCd])
    )  AS [Project1]
    ORDER BY [Project1].[intStudentStatusCd] ASC, [Project1].[datCreated] DESC
```

I've also tried

```
var students = (from x in db.vStudentProfiles
   let Child = new
   { 
       x.strLegalFirstName,
.....
   orderby x.intStudentStatusCd ascending, x.datCreated descending
   select Child
   ).ToList();
```

but as I expected didn't make a difference.

Use edmx with a single SQL Server View mapped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Not sure what is going on here, but my query is using every column even though I'm using a projection.

That's just the way EF generates queries.  EF expects the database engine to be smart enough to ignore the columns that are not used.  SQL Server is smart enough.

Comment: Not necessarily. I think this is specific for mapped database views in edmx.

Comment: Typical forest/trees issue. I wasn't expecting the non-used columns in the query at all, but EF wraps those in an inner select as opposed to just selecting the intended columns. Not sure why the inner select, but the end dataset has only the right columns. Seeing all those columns just threw me off I guess.